# what is wrong with the calculator coding?

Tags: batch-file

I was watching some Youtube videos for networking stuff (that is my career, atleast soon to be) and i came across on how to create a simple batch file. As i researched more, became interested just yesterday. I put a whole bunch of codes together to create a menu style batch file for me. The problem is that I am trying to create a calculator within a whole bunch of codes but it is not working!!! I have done some research but I cannot find it. Everyone says that I am doing the coding right. Also, i am trying to create columns in my menu and found some things but I do not know how to use the tab command. Can anyone help me?!?!?!? Here is the code that i wrote.

```
@echo off
echo What is your name? 
set /p name= 
echo Hello %name%!

:MENU
echo. 
echo    ....................................................
echo    Press 1, 2, or 3 to select your option, or 4 to exit
echo    ....................................................
echo.
echo    ---------------------------------------------------- 
echo                       1. Youtube 
echo                       2. Google 
echo                       3. Calculator
echo                       4. Open Office 
echo                       5. Craigslist
echo                       6. Gmail
echo                       7. Exit 
echo    ----------------------------------------------------
echo. 

set /p m=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press Enter: 
if %m%==1 goto Youtube
if %m%==2 goto Google
if %m%==3 goto Calcuator
if %m%==4 goto Open Office
if %m%==5 goto Craigslist
if %m%==6 goto Gmail
if %m%==7 goto Exit 
:Youtube
cls
START www.youtube.com
goto menu

:Google
cls
START www.google.com
goto menu

:Calculator
set /p math=equation?
set /a result=%math%
echo %result%
pause
cls
goto main

:Open Office
cls
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice.exe"
start soffice.exe
goto menu

:Craigslist
cls
start https://elpaso.craigslist.org
goto menu

:Gmail
cls
start www.gmail.com
goto menu
```

P.S. The other way i know the calculator coding is write is because I took that code and and put it in a separate editor and it works.

Comment: Can you tell us what is going wrong? What do you input, what should the output be, and what is the actual, wrong, output.

Comment: Btw, Welcom to StackOverflow! As you are a new member, please note that if you want to reply to a comment you should use for example @DennisvanGils, or else the person you're responding to won't get a notification.

Comment: If you turned off `echo off` you would have seen the error. Don't hide errors.

Comment: `md` simply ignores anything after the destination label in a `goto` so `goto open office` is executed as `goto open` (batch is largely case-insensitive.) Similarly, it works because the label `:open office` is interpreted as `:open`. This is a fail-to-fail scenario. It simply appears to work correctly but would fail if you were to add `open calc` for instance because you would then have 2 labels `:open`.

Comment: Also, consider using [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead of `set /p`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo in your reference to `Calculator`. You are trying to go to `Calcuator` which doesn't exist. By the way, you'll get another error after the calculator has performed the equation because there is no label called `main` to go to (I think you should replace with `GOTO MENU`)